# tableview with automatic row size based on content

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, tableview

I want to have a iOS table view. Each cell will have different cell contents ranging from 1 to 10 (max). I want the cell to resize automatically based on the size of the content.

I tried some existing solution which did not help.

Anyhelp on this? or any open source

Comment: You say you tried a solution but have not shown what that attempt was. Can you post the code and explain what is not working in it

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is done by having a class method on your cell class that will figure out the necessary height for a given piece of content. You then call this class method in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` tableview delegate method, passing in the content to the class method that will be used for that index path. Like so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Event* event = self.events[indexPath.row];

return [EventCell cellHeightForEvent:event];
}
```

In your cell height class method, you can figure out the size of your content by using methods like `sizeWithFont` on an NSString that you wish to display.

```
+ (CGFloat)cellHeightForEvent:(Event *)event {

    CGSize textSize = [event.title sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithNameB:@"Helvetica" size:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(67, MAXFLOAT)];

    CGFloat paddedHeight = textSize.height + 22;

    CGFloat min = 46;

    return MAX(min, paddedHeight);
}
```

This will cause your row height to be dynamic based on content. Note that you will have to resize your cell's views appropriately in `layoutSubviews` to be correct for the size of the content for each new row.

NOTE: The answers above that suggest hardcoding specific sizes to particular index paths are a very bad solution. You may not know the number of or ordering of your data elements, which renders this solution impossible. Also, if the data set changes (in number or ordering), you then have to go back and re-code your index paths to be correct again. The solution I have given will not need to be refactored for different or dynamic data sets.

Answer (score 1):

This is the one you are looking for:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 10.0f;
}
```

Based on indexPath you can return different height.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

indexPath.row will represent the index of the cell content and return its height.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom UITableViewCell subclass, layOut your cells and use the same logic to calculate the rowHeight in the delegate method as suggested above

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//calculate the height of your custom cell based on indexPath
return customCellHeightForRowAtIndexPath;
}
```